# help using hook_url_outbound_alter() to append "#id" to node/edit url

Tags: hooks

My node/edit form pages are long. When the user visits the node/edit page, I wish to direct the user toward the interesting part of that page. This part of the page has the id :   `<div id = "my_id">`

I try to use [hook_url_outbound_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7.x) to change the path node/xxx/edit into the path node/xxx/edit/#My_id

I began testing for a specific example with the code below. But it doesn't work : the path stays as original.

```
function MY_MODULE_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  if ($path == 'node/17609/edit?destination=node/17592') {
    $path = 'node/17609/edit?destination=node/17592#my_id';
  }
}
```

(I think that the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module could have done this but I can't install it on my website for incompatibility reason)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The `$options` parameter passed by reference to the `hook_url_outbound_alter()` implementations is described as follows. (Emphasis is mine.)

> `$options`: A set of URL options for the URL so elements such as **a fragment** or a **query string** can be added to the URL.

What that documentation page doesn't explicitly say is that `$options` is the same array [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7.x) accepts, which includes the following array indexes.

> - 'query': An array of query key/value-pairs (without any URL-encoding) to append to the URL.
> - 'fragment': A fragment identifier (named anchor) to append to the URL. Do not include the leading '#' character.

Comment: thanks for helping @kiamlaluno.  But my following (simplified) code doesn't work : the path stays inchanged. : 

`function my_module_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
 if ($path == 'node/17609/edit') {
   $options['fragment'] = 'my_id';
  }
}`